# Reading of standard input with fgets not waiting for input

Tags: c, string

Having this piece of code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[4];

    do
    {
        if (fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin) == NULL)
            break;
        printf("\n %s \n", str);
    }while (strncmp(str,"q\n",sizeof("q\n")));

    return 0;
}
```

if i type more than 4 characters, then two lines are displayed. if i type 123456 and then press enter, does input store ['1','2','\n','\0'] or ['1','2','3','\0']? hen the second time printf is reached if i only press enter key one time?. How i can avoid this behaviour? I would like type 123456 and then get:

```
1234
```

Comment: The expression `sizeof("q\n")` does **not** return the length of the string `"q\n"`.

Comment: Program ends when i type 'q'.

Comment: The expression `sizeof("q\n")` will return `3`, that is the size of the array created by the literal string `"q\n"` which, of course, also contain the terminating `'\0'` character. If you want to get the length of a string, use `strlen`. Always!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `fgets` is only reading partial input is because the `str` array is too small. You need to increase the buffer size of `str` array.

Also remember that `fgets` will pick up `\n` ( enter / return ) that you press after giving your input.

To get rid of the `\n` do this:

```
fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';
```

---

There is one **MAJOR** issue with your `while` condition ... I am not sure what your are trying to do there but `strcmp` is used to see if two strings are the same or not ... what you are doing is trying to compare a string to the size of something ...

Comment: But i want to store only first 4 characters of the user input. Now my questions was edited because some misprints.

Comment: you can do that by putting a `NUL`L character at the 5 index of `input` array : `fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);`
`input[5] = '\0';`

Comment: it doesnt work. if i declare str as char str[5], after fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin) i perform str[5] = '\0' but while loop including  printf is executed for two times.

Comment: @user2119381 Dude increase the size of `str`  ... make the input buffer bigger that your biggest input

Comment: @user2119381 also change that to str[4] = '\0';

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you do not include `<stdio.h>`.
- `fgets()` is given a very short buffer: 4 bytes, allowing for only 3 characters to be input at a time, including the `'\n'`. If you type more characters, they are buffered by the terminal and the standard stream library. It will take several calls to `fgets()` to read them all, 3 bytes at a time.
- Your termination test is bogus: `strncmp(str, "q\n", sizeof("q\n"))` compares the string read by `fgets()` with `"q\n"` upto a maximum number of characters of `3` because `sizeof("q\n")` counts the `q`, the `\n` **and** the null terminator. You should just use `strcmp()` for this test.
- You print the string with `printf("\n %s \n", str);`. Note however that a regular line read into `str` will contain the trailing newline so the `printf` call will actually output 2 lines.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[80];

    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) != NULL) {
        str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the newline if present
        printf("\n %s \n", str);
        if (!strcmp(str, "q"));
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Try using getc() or fgetc() before using fgets()**

When you use a `scanf()`, you press enter key (newline) which operates as accepting the input and transferring the input from stdin (standard input device) to your program.

`scanf()` itself does not consume the newline pressed. So, we need something down the code which will accept this newline and prevent this newline from acting as an input to the subsequent `fgets()`. This newline can be accepted using `getc()` or `fgetc()`, which should be written before `fgets()`.

`fgetc(stdin);` OR `getc(stdin)`;